# sum(.) on a factor column returns incorrect result

Tags: r, data.table

I am in a strange fix here. I am using `data.table` for a very routine task, but there is something that I am not able to explain. I have figured out a way around the problem, but I think it is still important for me to understand what is going wrong here.

This code will bring the data into workspace:

```
library(XML)
library(data.table)
theurl <- "http://goo.gl/hOKW3a"
tables <- readHTMLTable(theurl)
new.Res <- data.table(tables[[2]][4:5][-(1:2),])
suppressWarnings(names(new.Res) <- c("Party","Cases"))
```

There are two columns here, `Party` and `Cases`. Both of which have the default class of `factor`. Although, `Cases` should be `numeric`. Ultimately, I just want the sum of `Cases` for each `Party`. So something like this should work:

```
new.Res[,sum(Cases), by=Party]
```

But this doesn't give the right answer. I thought that it'll work if I change the class of `Cases` from `factor` to `numeric`. So I tried the following:

```
new.Res[,Cases := as.numeric(Cases)]
new.Res[,sum(Cases), by=Party]
```

But I got the same incorrect answer. I realized that the problem is happening in changing the class of `Cases` from `factor` to `numeric`. So I tried a different method, and it worked:

Step1: Reinitialize the data:

```
theurl <- "http://goo.gl/hOKW3a"
tables <- readHTMLTable(theurl)
new.Res <- data.table(tables[[2]][4:5][-(1:2),])
suppressWarnings(names(new.Res) <- c("Party","Cases"))
```

Step2: Use a different method to change the class from `factor` to `numeric`:

```
new.Res[,Cases := strtoi(Cases)]
new.Res[,sum(Cases), by=Party]
```

This works fine! However, I am not sure what's wrong with the first two methods. What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct way to convert from `factor` to `numeric` or `integer` is to go through `character`. This is because internally, a factor is an integer index (that refers to a `levels` vector). When you tell R to convert it to `numeric` it will simply convert the underlying index, not try to convert the level label.

Short answer: do `Cases:=as.numeric(as.character(Cases))`.

**Edit:** Alternatively the `?factor` help page suggests `as.numeric(levels(Cases))[Cases]` as more efficient. h/t @Gsee in the comments.

Comment: Everyone falls for that one @Shambo :-) It's a rite of passage.

Comment: This does seem to be the most common way, but note that `?factor` says "To transform a factor `f` to approximately its original numeric values, `as.numeric(levels(f))[f]` is recommended and slightly more efficient than `as.numeric(as.character(f))`."

Comment: I recalled reading something like this, but the common way is easier to remember.